# Jacoco maven plugin clogs up console with Exceptions-java.lang.IllegalStateException: class is already instrumented

Tags: java, powermock, instrumentation, jacoco-maven-plugin

I am working on sonar code coverage using Jacoco plugin and using power mock mockito combination to write JUnit test cases, while all goes well with the build when I run mvn clean install but the console shows a very very long stack trace chain which keeps coming for many many classes used in the project, and is quite irritating, 
The exception trace is similar to below-

```
java.lang.instrument.IllegalClassFormatException: Error while instrumenting class..
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Error while instrumenting class.
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Class <class-name> is already instrumented.
```

I went through below link for a solution but could not get a way out:-

```
https://github.com/jacoco/jacoco/issues/32
```

The link says "The error indicates that there are two JaCoCo agents configured for the same process, Looks like activation of surefire-report-plugin leads to a **doubled** agent, which is not an exceptional case, but an error in configuration of JVM for tests" In my case it is not even doubled agent I guess as my argLine has set to only one jacoco agent.

In my case, the argLine is set to below-

```
javaagent:C:\\Users\\user\\.m2\\repository\\org\\jacoco\\org.jacoco.agent\\0.7.6.201602180812\\org.jacoco.agent-0.7.6.201602180812-runtime.jar=destfile=C:Users\\user\\git\\package\\target\\jacoco.exec
```

My pom.xml entry for jacoco-sonar configuration is as below -

```
<properties>
        <sonar.sources>src/main/java</sonar.sources>
        <sonar.tests>src/test/java</sonar.tests>
        <sonar.java.coveragePlugin>jacoco</sonar.java.coveragePlugin>
        <sonar.jacoco.reportPaths>${project.basedir}/target/jacoco.exec</sonar.jacoco.reportPaths>
        <sonar.language>java</sonar.language>
        <sonar.binaries>${project.basedir}/target/classes</sonar.binaries>
        <sonar.inclusions>
            **/com/abc/service/impl/ABCServiceImpl.java,
            **/com/abc/dao/impl/ABCDAOImpl.java
        </sonar.inclusions>
    </properties>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.20</version>
                <configuration>
                    <skipTests>false</skipTests>
                    <argLine>-Xmx1024m -XX:MaxPermSize=256m ${argLine}</argLine>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
                <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>0.7.6.201602180812</version>
                <executions>
                 <execution>
                        <id>default-prepare-agent</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>prepare-agent</goal>
                        </goals>
                </execution> 
                <execution>
                    <id>default-instrument</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>instrument</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
                <execution>
                    <id>default-restore-instrumented-classes</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>restore-instrumented-classes</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>default-report</id>
                        <phase>prepare-package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>report</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
```

**Note**: If I remove the execution element for 'default-instrument' and 'default-restore-instrumented-classes' than the exception trace does not come but I get coverage = 0.0% on sonar dashboard, using these two execution elements give me correct code coverage but with lengthy stack trace on the console. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: _'The error indicates that there are two JaCoCo agents configured for the same process'_ this gave me a quick fix!. i had two javaagents configured at two different places in server startup. Removed one and it worked.

Comment: I am getting the same error but not on my local but on the Jenkins build, how do I know if there ar 2 java agents configured ? @ParamvirSinghKarwal

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As per my insight into this research:
It is possible to also use offline-instrumented classes with the JaCoCo Java agent. In this case, the configuration is taken from the agent options. The agent must be configured in a way that pre-instrumented classes are excluded, e.g. with " **excludes=*** ". Otherwise it will result in error messages on the console if the agent instruments such classes again likewise in your case.

The agent jacocoagent.jar is part of the JaCoCo distribution and includes all required dependencies. A Java agent can be activated with the following JVM option:

*-javaagent:[yourpath/]jacocoagent.jar=[option1]=[value1],[option2]=[value2]*

For JaCoCo agent options, consider the following link:
http://www.jacoco.org/jacoco/trunk/doc/agent.html

Comment: Thanks a ton @Stuti Verma , 
it worked your suggested inputs and I managed to get rid of long stacktrace :)

I added below entry for excludes=* as you told under jacoco plugin entry-

<configuration>
 <excludes>
   <exclude>*</exclude>
 </excludes>
</configuration>

Now my argLine looks like below :-

-javaagent:C:\\Users\\user\\.m2\\repository\\org\\jacoco\\org.jacoco.agent\\0.7.6.201602180812\\org.jacoco.agent-0.7.6.201602180812-runtime.jar=destfile=C:Users\\user\\git\\package\\target\\jacoco.exec,excludes=*

Answer (score 4):

I've also faced the same issue, but with Gradle. For me, the problem was with the following instructions

```
debug {
    testCoverageEnabled true
}
```

which I've added in accordance with one tutorial. It also instruments classes (as Jacoco does) and thus the exceptions are thrown.

Removing this instruction solved the problem for me.

Answer (score 0):

I use mockito instead of powermock, but I do not think that there is any difference for the usage with sonar. I use the [Sonar Maven Scanner](https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SCAN/Analyzing+with+SonarQube+Scanner+for+Maven) for the anlysis and it works like a charm.

My pom.xml contains the following properties

```
<properties>
    <project.source.version>1.8</project.source.version>
    <project.target.version>${project.source.version}</project.target.version>
    <sonar.scanner.version>3.3.0.603</sonar.scanner.version>
    <jacoco.maven.version>0.7.9</jacoco.maven.version>
    <sonar.projectName>MyProject</sonar.projectName>
    <sonar.projectKey>my-project-key</sonar.projectKey>
    <sonar.language>java</sonar.language>
</properties>
```

and the plugins are configured as follows

```
<plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.5.1</version>
            <inherited>true</inherited>
            <configuration>
                <source>${project.source.version}</source>
                <target>${project.target.version}</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.sonarsource.scanner.maven</groupId>
            <artifactId>sonar-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${sonar.scanner.version}</version>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
            <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${jacoco.maven.version}</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>prepare-agent</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
                <execution>
                    <id>report</id>
                    <phase>prepare-package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>report</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
```

You can run the analysis with

```
mvn clean install sonar:sonar
```

This generates a the default exec file lacated at target/jacoco.exec wich will be used by your local sonarqube server and contains also the coverage.

---

**Updated answer**

Tested it with powermock. I used the [powermock jacoco-offline example](https://github.com/powermock/powermock-examples-maven/tree/master/jacoco-offline) and just adapted it a little bit.

The pom.xml is then

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    4.0.0

```
<groupId>org.powermock</groupId>
<artifactId>jacoco-offline</artifactId>
<version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

<name>JaCoCo Offline with PowerMock</name>
<description>
    Example how to get code coverage with PowerMock
</description>

<properties>
    <jacoco.version>0.7.9</jacoco.version>
    <sonar.scanner.version>3.3.0.603</sonar.scanner.version>
    <!-- Used to locate the profile specific configuration file. -->
    <build.profile.id>dev</build.profile.id>

    <jacoco.it.execution.data.file>${project.build.directory}/coverage-reports/jacoco-it.exec</jacoco.it.execution.data.file>
    <jacoco.ut.execution.data.file>${project.build.directory}/coverage-reports/jacoco-ut.exec</jacoco.ut.execution.data.file>

    <jdk.version>1.8</jdk.version>

    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>

    <!-- Only unit tests are run by default. -->
    <skip.unit.tests>false</skip.unit.tests>

    <powermock.version>1.7.0</powermock.version>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.6</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.6</maven.compiler.target>
    <mockito1.version>1.10.19</mockito1.version>
    <mockito2.version>2.8.9</mockito2.version>
    <easymock.version>3.4</easymock.version>
    <assertj-core.version>3.8.0</assertj-core.version>
    <junit.version>4.12</junit.version>
    <spring.version>3.0.5.RELEASE</spring.version>
    <commons-lang3.version>3.4</commons-lang3.version>

     <sonar.jacoco.reportPaths>${project.basedir}/target/coverage.exec</sonar.jacoco.reportPaths>

</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.assertj</groupId>
        <artifactId>assertj-core</artifactId>
        <version>${assertj-core.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.powermock</groupId>
        <artifactId>powermock-api-mockito</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.powermock</groupId>
        <artifactId>powermock-core</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.powermock</groupId>
        <artifactId>powermock-module-junit4</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
        <artifactId>org.jacoco.agent</artifactId>
        <version>${jacoco.version}</version>
        <classifier>runtime</classifier>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
            <groupId>org.powermock</groupId>
            <artifactId>powermock-core</artifactId>
            <version>${powermock.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.powermock</groupId>
            <artifactId>powermock-api-mockito</artifactId>
            <version>${powermock.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.powermock</groupId>
            <artifactId>powermock-api-mockito2</artifactId>
            <version>${powermock.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.powermock</groupId>
            <artifactId>powermock-api-mockito-common</artifactId>
            <version>${powermock.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.powermock</groupId>
            <artifactId>powermock-api-support</artifactId>
            <version>${powermock.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.powermock</groupId>
            <artifactId>powermock-module-junit4-rule</artifactId>
            <version>${powermock.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.powermock</groupId>
            <artifactId>powermock-classloading-xstream</artifactId>
            <version>${powermock.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.powermock</groupId>
            <artifactId>powermock-module-junit4-rule-agent</artifactId>
            <version>${powermock.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.powermock</groupId>
            <artifactId>powermock-api-easymock</artifactId>
            <version>${powermock.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.powermock</groupId>
            <artifactId>powermock-module-testng</artifactId>
            <version>${powermock.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.powermock</groupId>
            <artifactId>powermock-module-junit4</artifactId>
            <version>${powermock.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.easymock</groupId>
            <artifactId>easymock</artifactId>
            <version>${easymock.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
            <artifactId>mockito-core</artifactId>
            <version>${mockito1.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>${junit.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
            <version>${commons-lang3.version}</version>
        </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>${jdk.version}</source>
                <target>${jdk.version}</target>
                <encoding>${project.build.sourceEncoding}</encoding>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
            <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${jacoco.version}</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>default-instrument</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>instrument</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
                <execution>
                    <id>default-restore-instrumented-classes</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>restore-instrumented-classes</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
                <execution>
                    <id>report</id>
                    <phase>prepare-package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>report</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <dataFile>${project.build.directory}/coverage.exec</dataFile>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.19.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <systemPropertyVariables>
                    <jacoco-agent.destfile>${project.build.directory}/coverage.exec</jacoco-agent.destfile>
                </systemPropertyVariables>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.sonarsource.scanner.maven</groupId>
            <artifactId>sonar-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${sonar.scanner.version}</version>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Thats all basic and you are right, I also missed the coverage. After run `mvn clean install` you can see the **coverage.exec** in the target folder. By default sonar is looking for a jacoco.exec file.

You can adapt this behaviour by just adding

```
<sonar.jacoco.reportPaths>${project.basedir}/target/coverage.exec</sonar.jacoco.reportPaths>
```

to the properties section in the pom.xml. After running `mvn clean install sonar:sonar` again the coverage is present in my local sonarqube. Hope this helps you more...

Comment: @Macro Kunis I dont agree with your first statement - "I use mockito instead of powermock, but I do not think that there is any difference."- Yes there are differences and advantages why one goes to powermock.
eg: - like you can not mock static/private/native methods and final classes with mockito. then you need to move to powermock.

Comment: @DeepakS This was a missunderstanding. I meant that there is no difference for the code analysis process with sonarqube. I edit my answer to clarify this

Comment: @Macro Kunis ok but there is a certainly a catch with jacoco with instrumentation with powermock , which is showing the stacktrace. looking for inputs from the community.

Comment: @DeepakS I tested it with a basic powermock example project and it works. Please have a look at my updated answer and verfiy if this works in general for you

Comment: @Macro Kunis I went through your updated answer but somehow it does not cover my case.

Comment: 1. I am using a different version  of jacoco maven plugin than yours, also the version you've used for maven-surefire-plugin is 2.19.1 and mine is 2.20.

Comment: Though I am not sure it is a version specific problem or not but in your updated answer there are lot many dependencies are involved like for mockito1, mockito2 and are hard to decipher , considering the mockito-powermock compatibility mentioned at https://github.com/powermock/powermock/wiki/Mockito

Comment: I have used Mockito 1.10.19 version with powermock 1.6.4 version.

Comment: 2.  As my issue did not solve , I had to use the excludes=* configuration mentioned in my response to @Stuti Verma 's answer which worked for me.

Comment: So just in case you stumble upon similar use case as mine you can use the <excludes> tag and use the jacocoagent insside argLine tag in case sonar not picking the jacocoagent automatically.

Comment: mind that : if we use argLine incorrectly (not appending ${argLine} inside <argLine> tag) , you end up getting 0% coverage shown on sonar dashboard.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using pom.xml and jacoco plugin for build then you need to update the configuration at "prepare-agent" stage of build so that  pre-instrumented classes are excluded as follows.

```
   <build>
            <plugins>
              <plugin>
                <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
                <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                  <execution>
                <id>default-instrument</id>
                <goals>
                    <goal>instrument</goal>
                </goals>
                  </execution>
                  <execution>
                <id>default-restore-instrumented-classes</id>
                <goals>
                    <goal>restore-instrumented-classes</goal>
                </goals>
                  </execution>
                  <execution>
                <id>prepare-agent</id>
                <goals>
                  <goal>prepare-agent</goal>
                </goals>
                <configuration> 
                <excludes> 
                <exclude>*</exclude> 
                </excludes> 
                </configuration>      
                  </execution>
                  <execution>
                <id>report</id>   
                <goals>
                  <goal>report</goal>
                </goals>
                  </execution>
                </executions>
              </plugin>
            </plugins>
              </build>
```

Answer (score 0):

This works for me

```
debug {
    // disable testCoverage to fix Jacoco instrument error
    testCoverageEnabled false
}
```